# How to convert a time in milli seconds to minutes in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am capturing elapsed time in simple variable in Jmeter and the value is saved in milliseconds, but I need to convert that value into minutes? Is there any way to do this in JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you could probably just use some simple math:
[Convert Milliseconds To Hours, Minutes, And Seconds](https://easyjmeter.wordpress.com/2016/03/07/convert-milliseconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds/)

Answer (score 1):

Given your variable name is `elapsed` you can convert milliseconds to minutes by dividing its value by 1000 (convert from ms to seconds) followed by dividing by 60 (convert seconds to minutes) via i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) which allows executing arbitrary [JEXL expressions](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/) like:

```
${__jexl3(${elapsed} / 1000 / 60,elapsed)}
```

The above function will convert the value from `${elapsed}` variable to minutes and write it back into `${elapsed}` variable.

- Functions can be used anywhere in the script
- Use [Function Helper Dialog](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) to simplify function development process
- See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on using JMeter Functions.